# Why ListCheckpointed expected java.util.List instead of scala native List

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading the souce code of the ListCheckpointed interface, it indicate the ListCheckpointed interface expect a java list instead of scala list. (I'm using the flink-scala)

I notice that the ListCheckpointed is a java interface, and that may be one of the reason. But what is the difference between java list and scala list

Thanks in advance

```java
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint;

import org.apache.flink.annotation.PublicEvolving;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.OperatorStateStore;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This interface can be implemented by functions that want to store state in checkpoints.
 * It can be used in a similar way as the deprecated {@link Checkpointed} interface, but
 * supports <b>list-style state redistribution</b> for cases when the parallelism of the
 * transformation is changed.
 *
 * <p>Implementing this interface is a shortcut for obtaining the default {@code ListState}
 * from the {@link OperatorStateStore}. Using the {@code OperatorStateStore} directly gives
 * more flexible options to use operator state, for example controlling the serialization
 * of the state objects, or have multiple named states.
 *
 * <h2>State Redistribution</h2>
 * State redistribution happens when the parallelism of the operator is changed.
 * State redistribution of <i>operator state</i> (to which category the state handled by this
 * interface belongs) always goes through a checkpoint, so it appears
 * to the transformation functions like a failure/recovery combination, where recovery happens
 * with a different parallelism.
 *
 * <p>Conceptually, the state in the checkpoint is the concatenated list of all lists
 * returned by the parallel transformation function instances. When restoring from a checkpoint,
 * the list is divided into sub-lists that are assigned to each parallel function instance.
 *
 * <p>The following sketch illustrates the state redistribution.The function runs with parallelism
 * <i>3</i>. The first two parallel instance of the function return lists with two state elements,
 * the third one a list with one element.
 * <pre>
 *    func_1        func_2     func_3
 * +----+----+   +----+----+   +----+
 * | S1 | S2 |   | S3 | S4 |   | S5 |
 * +----+----+   +----+----+   +----+
 * </pre>
 *
 * <p>Recovering the checkpoint with <i>parallelism = 5</i> yields the following state assignment:
 * <pre>
 * func_1   func_2   func_3   func_4   func_5
 * +----+   +----+   +----+   +----+   +----+
 * | S1 |   | S2 |   | S3 |   | S4 |   | S5 |
 * +----+   +----+   +----+   +----+   +----+
 * </pre>

 * Recovering the checkpoint with <i>parallelism = 2</i> yields the following state assignment:
 * <pre>
 *      func_1          func_2
 * +----+----+----+   +----+----+
 * | S1 | S2 | S3 |   | S4 | S5 |
 * +----+----+----+   +----+----+
 * </pre>
 *
 * <h2>Example</h2>
 * The following example illustrates how to implement a {@code MapFunction} that counts all elements
 * passing through it, keeping the total count accurate under re-scaling  (changes or parallelism):
 * <pre>{@code
 * public class CountingFunction<T> implements MapFunction<T, Tuple2<T, Long>>, ListCheckpointed<Long> {
 *
 *     // this count is the number of elements in the parallel subtask
 *     private long count;
 *
 *     {@literal @}Override
 *     public List<Long> snapshotState(long checkpointId, long timestamp) {
 *         // return a single element - our count
 *         return Collections.singletonList(count);
 *     }
 *
 *     {@literal @}Override
 *     public void restoreState(List<Long> state) throws Exception {
 *         // in case of scale in, this adds up counters from different original subtasks
 *         // in case of scale out, list this may be empty
 *         for (Long l : state) {
 *             count += l;
 *         }
 *     }
 *
 *     {@literal @}Override
 *     public Tuple2<T, Long> map(T value) {
 *         count++;
 *         return new Tuple2<>(value, count);
 *     }
 * }
 * }</pre>
 *
 * @param <T> The type of the operator state.
 */
@PublicEvolving
public interface ListCheckpointed<T extends Serializable> {

    /**
     * Gets the current state of the function. The state must reflect the result of all prior
     * invocations to this function.
     *
     * <p>The returned list should contain one entry for redistributable unit of state. See
     * the {@link ListCheckpointed class docs} for an illustration how list-style state
     * redistribution works.
     *
     * <p>As special case, the returned list may be null or empty (if the operator has no state)
     * or it may contain a single element (if the operator state is indivisible).
     *
     * @param checkpointId The ID of the checkpoint - a unique and monotonously increasing value.
     * @param timestamp The wall clock timestamp when the checkpoint was triggered by the master.
     *
     * @return The operator state in a list of redistributable, atomic sub-states.
     *         Should not return null, but empty list instead.
     *
     * @throws Exception Thrown if the creation of the state object failed. This causes the
     *                   checkpoint to fail. The system may decide to fail the operation (and trigger
     *                   recovery), or to discard this checkpoint attempt and to continue running
     *                   and to try again with the next checkpoint attempt.
     */
    List<T> snapshotState(long checkpointId, long timestamp) throws Exception;

    /**
     * Restores the state of the function or operator to that of a previous checkpoint.
     * This method is invoked when the function is executed after a failure recovery.
     * The state list may be empty if no state is to be recovered by the particular parallel instance
     * of the function.
     *
     * <p>The given state list will contain all the <i>sub states</i> that this parallel
     * instance of the function needs to handle. Refer to the  {@link ListCheckpointed class docs}
     * for an illustration how list-style state redistribution works.
     *
     * <p><b>Important:</b> When implementing this interface together with {@link RichFunction},
     * then the {@code restoreState()} method is called before {@link RichFunction#open(Configuration)}.
     *
     * @param state The state to be restored as a list of atomic sub-states.
     *
     * @throws Exception Throwing an exception in this method causes the recovery to fail.
     *                   The exact consequence depends on the configured failure handling strategy,
     *                   but typically the system will re-attempt the recovery, or try recovering
     *                   from a different checkpoint.
     */
    void restoreState(List<T> state) throws Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have kinda answered your own question. The `ListCheckpointed` is written in Java, so basically it uses the Java collections. As for the differences between Java and Scala `List`, they are different constructs with different methods and they cannot be used interchangeably even though they have similar working principles. You can however convert between Java and Scala collections. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) to get more info on that.